# how to connect with social web sites and get information without getting redirected to their site?

Tags: java

when we use these apis

•For Twitter: twitter4j
•For Facebook: fb-java-api
•For Linkedin: linkedin-j

we will be redirected to the concern website, 
but my question is in my own java application user needs to give the credentials only once 
and having them i try to fetch information from these social websites to avoid user 
using all social websites to get connect

Comment: Hi guys i don't understand that why you people downvote me, i just asked what i don't know,

Comment: Me neither, I though it was a good question, only the grammar was wrong.

Comment: @Bradan I believe the reason of the downvotes is that this is a question that can be easily solved by searching in Google or in this site. You are asking to be spoon-fed the tools/steps, without a minimal effort of trying yo find them first. We would expect a question like "I'm getting this error connecting to Twitter" not something akin to "I didn't even bother to check on Twitter's site how to connect to their services, tell me how it is done".

Comment: @PereVillega i seached for the same in google and got few information on that. when we use these apis we will be redirected to the concern website, but my question is in my own java application user needs to give the credentials only once and having them i try to fetch information from these social websites to avoid user using all social websites to get connect. Hope you can help on this if possible.

Comment: @Mat,@casperone how come you guys close this when this in discussion? I thinks it is not fare and the question is very clear also i clarified the same. Please read the FAQ first and don't close when it is in discussion.

Comment: @Bradan: can't answer for the moderator, but for myself: your question doesn't show any research effort on your part, and it's pretty broad. Typing the first sentence as is in a search engine will lead you to a lot of alternatives & information to get you started (including Spring Social in the top links). Also, read the [faq] yourself. Discussions are **not** welcome on SO.

Comment: @Mat this is the place where we get help,after much googling only i asked this question and still have not got answer also. There are api which redirects to the concern website but what i have asked here, see comments for more info

Comment: @Mate i seached for the same in google and got few information on that. when we use these apis we will be redirected to the concern website, but my question is in my own java application user needs to give the credentials only once and having them i try to fetch information from these social websites to avoid user using all social websites to get connect. Hope you can help on this if possible.

Comment: @Bradan: none of that appears in your question. Add more details, _including_ what you found by searching, _and_ how that doesn't solve your problem (which you haven't described _at all_ in the question).

Comment: @Mat : so that i added comment and explained everything, why could you not answer as you have understod the problem ? instead of these kind of comment you can help to come out of this problem. what is your openion?

Comment: Comment aren't meant to last. You need to edit your question so that it is complete, by itself, without the comments.

Comment: @Mat: still you are not able to give answer instead just draging the conversation,anyway thanks for the information, i will edit the question. incase you are able you are always welcome to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social).

> Spring Social is an extension of the Spring Framework that allows you to connect your applications with Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) providers such as Facebook and Twitter.

FEATURES

- An extensible service provider framework that greatly simplifies the process of connecting local user accounts to hosted provider accounts.
- A connect controller that handles the authorization flow between your Java/Spring web application, a service provider, and your users.
- Java bindings to popular service provider APIs such as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, TripIt, and GitHub.
- A sign-in controller that enables users to authenticate with your application by signing in through a service provider.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many ways.

- raw REST access - you make HTTP requests and parse the responses (low-level, not recommended)
- spring-social - it's a subproject of spring, but you can use it without spring. It has support for most social networks
- per-network clients, like restfb, twitter4j, linkedinj - also a good option.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is download an appropriate API and use it in your programs.

- For Twitter: [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)
- For Facebook: [fb-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/)
- For Linkedin: [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/)

Using API makes the whole process simple.

Do a google search and you will find more.